Access static library .a file to .Net MAUI class library and build After building Access that .dll for new .Net MAUI iOS application
How to link .a static library in to .Net MAUI Class library and how to use that .dll in to sample project?

Creating a .NetMaui class library. in that i am adding .a file static library which is build from c++.
Example:
AddByCase


Created Wrapper.cs class in class library and accessing that APIs
Ex:
const string DllName = "__Internal";

 [DllImport(DllName, EntryPoint = "AddByCase", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]  //Entry Point name has to be same name as in .a File
        internal static extern long AddByCase(int SequenceNumber, double Quantity, StringBuilder ItemUPC, StringBuilder CaseUPC, double Price, int Pack, int InnerPack, StringBuilder ErrorMessage);


Linking the .a file in the class library project using below
path:
Platforms\\iOS\\Lib\\.     // This is the path where i have .a file inside the project

Below code is in .CSProj
<ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Platforms\iOS\Lib\libController.a" />
    </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
    <NativeReference Include="Platforms\iOS\Lib\libController.a">
        <Kind>Static</Kind>
        <ForceLoad>True</ForceLoad>
     </NativeReference>
</ItemGroup>


Building the project and creating .dll successfully. While using this .dll file in to main project i am getting so many errors like below. what is missing?

like/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_18.0/18.0.8316/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1648,3): error : clang++ exited with code 1: [/Users/sadeesh.kumar/Documents/Project/MauiApp4/MauiApp4/MauiApp4.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]


/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_18.0/18.0.8316/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1648,3): error : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: [/Users/sadeesh.kumar/Documents/Project/MauiApp4/MauiApp4/MauiApp4.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]


/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_18.0/18.0.8316/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1648,3): error :   "_Abort", referenced from: [/Users/sadeesh.kumar/Documents/Project/MauiApp4/MauiApp4/MauiApp4.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]


/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_18.0/18.0.8316/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1648,3): error :        [/Users/sadeesh.kumar/Documents/Project/MauiApp4/MauiApp4/MauiApp4.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]


/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_18.0/18.0.8316/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1648,3): error :   "_AddByCase", referenced from: [/Users/sadeesh.kumar/Documents/Project/MauiApp4/MauiApp4/MauiApp4.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]


/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_18.0/18.0.8316/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1648,3): error :        [/Users/sadeesh.kumar/Documents/Project/MauiApp4/MauiApp4/MauiApp4.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]



Environment:

Visual studio code: Version: 1.96.2
MacOS: 14.7.1
XCode: 16.2
DotNet-SDK: 8.0.404

.dill linking in to main project like below Lib-File is the folder name in which i have .dll files
<ItemGroup> <Reference Include="CSharpLib"> <HintPath>Lib-File\CSharpLib.dll</HintPath> </Reference> </ItemGroup>

AddByCase API is present in .a file i checked by using nm -C file.a
Is there a linking problem in class library project?
i have tried linking like this
Try 1:
 <ItemGroup>
    <NativeReference Include="Platforms\iOS\Lib\libController.a">
        <Kind>Static</Kind>
        <ForceLoad>True</ForceLoad>
     </NativeReference>
</ItemGroup>

Try 2:
<ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Platforms\iOS\Lib\libController.a" />
    </ItemGroup>

In main project i am using the .dll which is from class library like this
<ItemGroup> <Reference Include="CSharpLib"> <HintPath>Lib-File\CSharpLib.dll</HintPath> </Reference> </ItemGroup>


Are you having problem with this step: Wrapping the native libraries with a Visual Studio solution? Although this document is Xamarin, it also applies to MAUI.
